# minimizing the video file size when capturing a video in windows phone 8

Tags: vb.net, video, windows-phone-8, compression, resolution

I am recording a video in my app and uploading it to a server. The app is working fine for small videos but if the video is longer than 10 seconds the video size becomes very big and the app crashes.

How can I minimize the size of the video? Can I set the resolution? Can I also compress the video?

What else do you recommend I do to make sure the video is not gigantic?

Here is my code :

```
Public Sub InitializeVideoRecorder()
        If captureSource Is Nothing Then
            ' Create the VideoRecorder objects.
            captureSource = New CaptureSource()
            fileSink = New FileSink()

            videoCaptureDevice = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice()

            ' Add eventhandlers for captureSource.
            AddHandler captureSource.CaptureFailed, AddressOf OnCaptureFailed

            ' Initialize the camera if it exists on the device.
            If videoCaptureDevice IsNot Nothing Then
                ' Create the VideoBrush for the viewfinder.
                videoRecorderBrush = New VideoBrush()
                videoRecorderBrush.SetSource(captureSource)

                ' Display the viewfinder image on the rectangle.
                viewfinderRectangle.Fill = videoRecorderBrush

                ' Start video capture and display it on the viewfinder.
                captureSource.Start()

                ' Set the button state and the message.
                UpdateUI(ButtonState.Initialized, "")
            Else
                ' Disable buttons when the camera is not supported by the device.
                UpdateUI(ButtonState.CameraNotSupported, "A camera is not supported on this device.")
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the video size we can make the resolution as much low.The code

```
VideoCaptureDevice webcam = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice();

 int videoformatcount = webcam.SupportedFormats.Count(); //We will get the avilable video format

  if (videoformatcount > 0)
             {
                var Temp = webcam.SupportedFormats;

                VideoFormat objVideoFormat = Temp[videoformatcount - 1];

                webcam.DesiredFormat = new VideoFormat(PixelFormatType.Format8bppGrayscale, objVideoFormat.PixelWidth, objVideoFormat.PixelHeight, 1);
            }

captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice = webcam;
```

It will help you.The video must be in very low resolution(Available).